# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../aws-exports' causes automatic build in Vercel to fail

Tags: aws-amplify, vercel

I use Amplify for my backend and have a typescript app combined with React in my frontend. I am using Vercel to host my app and for my CI/CD pipeline. I am able to build my app successfully and to use the backend deployed services, for local host  and in production. However I am unable to make my CI/CD in Vercel to work because I get this error -
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../aws-exports'`
I understand the error and why it happens - Vercel cannot find the file because it is not pushed to the repo (as far as I understand for security reasons) and I understand I need somehow to connect the machine that builds in Vercel with my app in Amplify , but I cannot understand how to do this. Is there anything ready out of the box that can help me with that ? Or any other explanation that can help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a partial solution here - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/22556

Not fully automatic because it requires to set the env variable on each change of the aws-exports.js , but better than nothing.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.